# Solving simultaneous exponential equations

Tags: equation-solving

```
In[1]: Solve[{(1 + k)^n == 0.6, (1 + k)^(n + 1) == 0.3}, {n, k}]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some
>   solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
>   information. >>

```
Out[1]: {{n -> 0.736966, k -> -0.5}}

In[2]: Solve[{2*(1 + k)^n == 1.2, (1 + k)^(n + 1) == 0.3}, {n, k}]
```

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of
>   inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used
>   by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of
>   the system may help. >>

```
Out[2]: Solve[{2 (1 + k)^n == 1.2, (1 + k)^(1 + n) == 0.3}, {n, k}]
```

Where is the problem with Mathematica, not able to divide by 2 in first equation?

Comment: I don't know why the second system wasn't amenable to `Solve` (perhaps representation error in the decimal `1.2`, which results in a rationalized form not equal to `12/10`). But that second system *is* amenable to `Reduce`.

Comment: (e^-\[Theta]x \[Theta]^2)/(1 + \[Theta])
any one help me to solve this equation .i wana fifind value of x from this function..

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Solve to use Reduce,
[Reference to Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html)

```
Solve[{2*(1 + k)^n == 1.2, (1 + k)^(n + 1) == 0.3}, {n, k}, 
Method -> Reduce]
(*{{n -> ConditionalExpression[-1.4427 (-0.510826 + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[
     1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
      k -> ConditionalExpression[-0.5, C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[Rationalize@{2*(1 + k)^n == 1.2, (1 + k)^(n + 1) == 0.3}, {n,  k}, Reals]
(*
 {{n -> (-Log[3] + Log[5])/Log[2], k -> -(1/2)}}
*)
```

or:

```
Solve[{2*(1 + k)^n == 1.2, (1 + k)^(n + 1) == 0.3}, {n, k}, Reals]
(*
 {{n -> 0.736966, k -> -0.5}}
*)
```

Comment: The answers so far don't explain why merely doubling each side of the first of the two equations converts a system that `Solve` can handle to a system that it cannot.

Comment: @murray _I believe_ your comment on the question is right. `Solve[]` found both an exact (`2`) and an inexact (`1.2`) number on the same equation, and without specifying the domain (Reals) it doesn't know how to proceed